# button onclick event to occur only once usin DOM addEventListener()

Tags: javascript, button, onclick

I am creating dynamic set of buttons

```
for (var i = 0; i < clr.length; ++i) {
    button = document.createElement("button");
    button.innerHTML = clr[i];
    button.addEventListener('click', event);
    button.style.backgroundColor = clr[i];
    document.body.appendChild(button);
}
```

but I want the event to occur "only once" for each button. But I am unable to implement this correctly using javascript .

Comment: It's working fine [here](http://jsfiddle.net/VXk7X/)! Where do you stuck?

Comment: @DhavalMarthak OP wants to execute the click event only once for each button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove the attached event using [**removeEventListener**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.removeEventListener) once after it executed.  By doing this the click event is handled only once as mentioned below,

```
function event(e) {  //e represented the current element which is clicked
    e.target.removeEventListener(e.type, arguments.callee);
    alert('hi');
}
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/VXk7X/1/)

Comment: wow!..it really worked.. wasn't aware of such method . Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Shweta I'm glad I was able to help you.